# Constant Expression Required When Using an Array With a Switch Statement

Tags: java, arrays, char, switch-statement

Hello StackOverflow community, I've just begun to work with arrays and I was wondering how I can make the switch statement work with the values below. It's really irritating that it won't work considering the only error is constant expression required:

```
import java.lang.Character;

public class Ass11a {

    public static char[] vowel = new char[4];
    public static char[] consonant = new char[20];
    public static char[] number = new char[9];
    public static char[] punctuation = new char[10];
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EasyReader console = new EasyReader();
        System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
        char input = console.readChar();
        Character.toLowerCase(input);
        vowel[0] = 'a';
        vowel[1] = 'e';
        vowel[2] = 'i';
        vowel[3] = 'o';
        vowel[4] = 'u';

        consonant[0] = 'q';
        consonant[1] = 'w';
        consonant[2] = 'r';
        consonant[3] = 't';
        consonant[4] = 'y';
        consonant[5] = 'p';
        consonant[6] = 's';
        consonant[7] = 'd';
        consonant[8] = 'f';
        consonant[9] = 'g';
        consonant[10] = 'h';
        consonant[11] = 'j';
        consonant[12] = 'k';
        consonant[13] = 'l';
        consonant[14] = 'z';
        consonant[15] = 'x';
        consonant[16] = 'c';
        consonant[17] = 'v';
        consonant[18] = 'b';
        consonant[19] = 'n';
        consonant[20] = 'm';

        number[0] = '1';
        number[1] = '2';
        number[2] = '3';
        number[3] = '4';
        number[4] = '5';
        number[5] = '6';
        number[6] = '7';
        number[7] = '8';
        number[8] = '9';
        number[9] = '0';

        punctuation[0] = '.';
        punctuation[1] = ',';
        punctuation[2] = '?';
        punctuation[3] = '!';
        punctuation[4] = ';';
        punctuation[5] = ':';
        punctuation[6] = '"';
        punctuation[7] = '\'';
        punctuation[8] = '(';
        punctuation[9] = ')';
        punctuation[10] = '-';                                                                                                                                               
        switch(input)
        {
            case vowel[0]:case vowel[1]:case vowel[2]:case vowel[3]:case vowel[4]:
                System.out.println("Vowel");
                break;
            case consonant[0]:case consonant[1]:case consonant[2]:case consonant[3]:
            case consonant[4]:case consonant[5]:case consonant[6]:case consonant[7]:
            case consonant[8]:case consonant[9]:case consonant[10]:case consonant[11]:
            case consonant[12]:case consonant[13]:case consonant[14]:case consonant[15]:
            case consonant[16]:case consonant[17]:case consonant[18]:case consonant[19]:
            case consonant[20]:
                System.out.println("Consonant");
                break;
            case number[0]:case number[1]:case number[2]:case number[3]:case number[4]:
            case number[5]:case number[6]:case number[7]:case number[8]:case number[9]: 
                System.out.println("Number"); 
                break;                              
            case punctuation[0]:case punctuation[1]:case punctuation[2]:case punctuation[3]:
            case punctuation[4]:case punctuation[5]:case punctuation[6]:case punctuation[7]:
            case punctuation[8]:case punctuation[9]:case punctuation[10]:       
                System.out.println("Punctuation");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Other"); 
                break;              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `punctuation[0]` a constant expression? No. So you cannot use it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis So how would I go about editing it while maintaining the switch statement?

Comment: Didn't you get IndexOutOfBounds at `vowel[4]`?

Comment: You cannot. You must use constant expressions. That is a keyword, start by looking it up.

Comment: replace `case vowel[0]` with `case 'a'` etc because that is constant (can not change at runtime / the compiler knows the value already)

Comment: You might be better off with regular expressions here.  But if your instructor asked you to use `switch`, you'll have to use constant expressions/literals, because the Java language specification (section 14.11 in edition 3) says so.

Comment: "Note that Character.isLowerCase(Character.toLowerCase(ch)) does not always return true for some ranges of characters, particularly those that are symbols or ideographs." Might be something to look at straight out of the Character API.

Comment: If you have an array and you want to see if your value is equal to some element in the array, it's easy to do with a loop.  Even better might be to use a [Set<Character>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of an array.  This is not a good situation to use a `switch` statement.

Comment: What's the point of having all those cases if you're just going to fall through all of them.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an `enum` like this

```
public enum Vowels {
  A,E,I,O,U;
  static boolean isVowel(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'A': case 'a':
    case 'E': case 'e':
    case 'I': case 'i':
    case 'O': case 'o':
    case 'U': case 'u': return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  static Vowels getVowel(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'A': case 'a': return A;
    case 'E': case 'e': return E;
    case 'I': case 'i': return I;
    case 'O': case 'o': return O;
    case 'U': case 'u': return U;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  while (console.hasNextLine()) {
    String input = console.nextLine();
    for (Character ch : input.toCharArray()) {
      if (Vowels.isVowel(ch)) {
        System.out.println(ch + " is vowel");
      }
    }
  }
}
```